# Translating "Mother's son" into Latin

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, familia

Could you please help me translate "mother's son" into Latin?

From my understanding it is "*filius matris*" but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can be 100% sure.

Just watch out, though; "His mother's son" will be *Filius matris suae,* because *suae* agrees in gender number and case with (genitive, feminine, singular) *matris.*

"Her Mother's son" is also *Filius Matris suae*: Think of it as modern 'their Mother's son' even when 'their' means only one person. (But it is ambiguous)

Comment: @Josephine Hugh updated his answer to address that. You should vote up (the little arrow next to the answer) any answer (or question) you find helpful and accept an answer (the check mark next to the arrows) to indicate that your question has been fully answered. Accepting and voting are the way to reward people for their efforts on these Stack Exchange sites.